# How can I generate random colors, but always in the same order?

Tags: php, random, colors

I am generating a list of colors for calendar events but I don't want the colors to change every time you refresh the calendar. So I was wondering if there's a way to have the colors generated in the same order every time.

Right now I am using something like this:

```
function random_color() 
{
    return '#' . str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: If you don't want them to change, why are they random?

Comment: If you don't want them to be random, just create an array and use it. Don't use `mt_rand()`.

Comment: I thought of an array but let's say I have 1000 events by the end of the year, I would have to make an array of 1000 different hexcolor no?

Comment: Create your list of random colors and then store them?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the PRNG with the same seed every time. This way, the random number sequence will always be the same.
Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php

Answer (score 0):

well, without being able to tell exactly what you are trying to do this is my suggestion. I am assuming you do not want them to change on page reload.

so, what you can do, is define your colors and store them in a session array...

try for instance:

```
$_SESSION['events_colors'][123] = array('color'=>random_color());
```

123 would be replaced byu the ID of your event, this way when you need to reload the data and display the colors you can access that stored color with

```
$_SESSION['events_colors'][123]['color']
$_SESSION['events_colors'][124]['color']
$_SESSION['events_colors'][125]['color']
$_SESSION['events_colors'][etc]['color']
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mt_srand()` to seed the random number generator:

```
function random_color() 
{
    return '#' . str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

mts_rand(9000);

var_dump(
    random_color(),
    random_color(),
    random_color()
);
```

For an example, see:

- https://3v4l.org/5fNBd

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php

Alternatively, you could use [`fzaninotto/faker`](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to generate your random colors. The library allows as well to seed the `Faker\Generator`, see [Seeding the Generator](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/tree/v1.7.1#seeding-the-generator):

> You may want to get always the same generated data - for instance when using Faker for unit testing purposes. The generator offers a `seed()` method, which seeds the random number generator. Calling the same script twice with the same seed produces the same results.

```
use Faker\Factory;

$faker = Factory::create();
$faker->seed(9000);

var_dump(
    $faker->hexColor,
    $faker->hexColor,
    $faker->hexColor
);
```

For reference, see:

- https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/tree/v1.7.1#basic-usage
- https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/tree/v1.7.1#fakerprovidercolor
- https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker/tree/v1.7.1#seeding-the-generator